# What are the steps to add a different background to every slide in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am creating a presentation on PowerPoint. Can any tell me how can I add a different background to every slide in my presentation?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best doing this to the individual slides, not in the Slide Master, drop image in to the slide and send to back or format the **background** of the slide. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose the slide you want to change. Right click on it and select 'Format Background'. A Format Background dialog box appears. Select picture or texture fill and click on the file. 
Then choose your background image and apply it to your slide by clicking on Insert.Continue using these steps for each and every slide to create different backgrounds.